# How to link (syncfusion chart package) to API link in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, package, flutter-packages

I want to link the API by the syncfusion chart Flutter package with an API link like this:

An API like this

```
https://api.myproject/v2/price
```

I researched how to fix this, but I got  should to make the API like:

```
https://api.myproject/v2/price.json
```

But I see this is not the best for my business.
I see the first is best then.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: no problem but I want to use this package because it is good for me

Comment: I want to drive a ferrari.  It looks like fun.  Yeah, just wanting to use something does not give you the rights.

Comment: ok, what is your opinion I want to use another free package.

Comment: There are many charting packages in the pub.